# how to place =importxml result to a google script array?

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Could any one show me how i can add result of `=importxml` into an array inside google script. For example this the request inside google script :

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.google.com/search?q=bmw&safe=off&tbs=qdr:d","//h3[@class='r']")
```

I want later iterate the array to look for specific String!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option you can try is:

```js
/* CODE FOR DEMONSTRATION PURPOSES */
function ImportXML2Array() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(),
      range,
      values_array;
  sheet.getRange("A1").setFormula('=IMPORTXML("https://www.google.com/search?q=bmw&safe=off&tbs=qdr:d"; "//h3[@class=\'r\']")');
  range = sheet.getDataRange();
  values_array = range.getValues();
  range.clear();
  Logger.log(values_array);
}
/* CODE FOR DEMONSTRATION PURPOSES */
```

Comment: Many thanks . I used view logs and it confirmed that data is in the array! Now i want to iterate the array to see if the data exist in sheet B and insert each array item only if it doesn't exist on sheet B. is it possible to copy array items in different sheet inside array loop since your code clears the current sheet and old data get erased? How ? (since your code clears the current sheet i had to think of a way to copy array data to different sheet if its not already there) note: i will be calling this multiple times so i will get new data

Comment: @user1788736: You can access all the sheets of your spreadsheet without any problem. See [Class Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet) documentation.